# Check value of system function

Tags: c, return-value

i want to find the return value of mount command pass into system function in c language how can i do this

for example :

```
printf("return val = %d",WEXITSTATUS(system(mount /dev/sda /media/mmcblk0)));
```

but every time it gives me 255 value

can any one help me how can i find return code fired my mount command

or any other solution

NOTE: I have include header files properly

Thanks**strong text**

Comment: Check if `system` returned -1 for error.

Comment: Can you please post more complete code?  This code won't even compile.

Comment: are you running your program with `sudo` rights? I am pretty sure that mount requires sudo on most systems

Comment: The argument to system should be a `char*`, you need to put quotes around your mount command. Also, a minimal compilable example would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the command is in the upper 8 bits of the return value. So you bitwise shift the return value by 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
        int ret;
        ret = system("mount /dev/sda /media/mmcblk0");
        fprintf(stdout, "system ret:[%d]\n", (((ret)>>8) & 0xFF));
}
```

`WEXITSTATUS` is a macro, that's how it's defined above. It's likely if you are getting a return value of 255, that the command did not execute properly. As someone else alluded to, it could be because of permissions.

Therefore, if `system()` returns -1, then if you use the bit shift shown above the return code is 255.

Comment: May be the mount command is mainly used by the root user only so try to run the program as a root user.

Comment: @user3360662: Try something more simple.. like "cp test.txt /tmp" (Have to first have a test.txt file in current directory where program is run, of course.. If errno is 0, then it's not system, it's the mount command not working

Comment: i am using this command on dm814X board and have only root user permission also i have cross compile mount command on board

Comment: This is a problem on your hardware